# How Do I publish Visual Basic Application on Visual Studio to IIS Web Server?

Tags: visual-studio, iis, webserver

I programmed an application on visual studio using visual basic (Windows Forms) and now am attempting to publish the application to my IIS server but the option does not appear as I have seen in some Youtube videos. I have seen the option of Web Server (IIS) for some people's target publish, however, this option does not appear for me. Any Ideas?

[image]

Comment: WinForms applications are not published to IIS.

Comment: @Lexi Li So my best bet would be to set up an azure account and go that way?

Comment: Your best bet is to first know what exactly is the application type you want to develop, desktop or web. And then you might learn the proper way of distributing it via MSI/MSIX for desktops, or hosting it on a web server/Azure for the web.